# remove rec. from middle of line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to remove specific characters, such as 'rec.', from rec.cbr_cur_book_bal which is part of line of pl/sql code

```
update leasemaster
set
BAS_CBR_EB_RWA = bas2_rwa_calc(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD,nvl(REC.cbr_cur_book_bal,0), nvl(v_bas_cap_factor_k,0), v_basel_min, v_bas_rwa_rate)
```

Comment: Search and replace ? http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Searching_And_Replacing

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\brec\.`
- Replace with: `EAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary, make sure we don't match "trec"
rec             # literally
\.              # a dot
```

**Result for given example:**

```
update leasemaster
set
BAS_CBR_EB_RWA = bas2_rwa_calc(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD,nvl(cbr_cur_book_bal,0), nvl(v_bas_cap_factor_k,0), v_basel_min, v_bas_rwa_rate)
```